# What does a beep code of 8-4-8 mean on a Gigabyte Ultra-Durable motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

I can't figure out this code, there is nothing about it anywhere.
It starts with 8 beeps, then in a higher tone goes beep-beepbeepbeep, and then repeats the 8 beep sequence.

What does this mean, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Which motherboard do you have? The Gigabyte ultra durable is a series of motherboards and isn't really specific enough to diagnose. Also, has this pc ever worked? What has changed? Did you build it yourself? My first instinct would be to check the RAM. Maybe try a stick at a time and see if you still get beeps. You might also want to try reseating the graphics card. Also, make sure all the power cables are connected. Most motherboards have more than one power connector

Comment: "8 short beep：Graphic card error"  ....https://www.gigabyte.com/Support/FAQ/816